# Can't add extra row or column in Google Charts table code.. (the table disappears)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using this Javascript code from Google - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table

I am trying to add more rows and columns, but every time I add something the table disappears.

```
data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
```

or `['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

      function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
        data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
          ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
          ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
          ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
        ]);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="table_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What research have you done? Have you tried debugging, even with print statements? Can you use browser developer mode to inspect the runtime? [Edit] the question and tell us what you have done so far.

Comment: I just realized that I was trying to add 'number' not 'string'. So I tried to add (mis) as extra column and it worked! 

 data.addRows([
          ['Mike', 'mis',  {v: 75365, f: '$10,000'}, true],'

Comment: I am new in JS and wondering what is 'v: and f:' for the number?

also when you said browser developer mode, you meant google inspect?

Comment: All modern browsers have a "Developer Mode". Dig around in the options or search the web for your browser.

Comment: Your question about the syntax in the code sounds like a new question. But a web search got me to https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#cell_object